# azure traffic manager degraded

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

currently I wanna host website by using azure CDN and azure blob storage, I wanna do the CDN failover and recovery management to handle the situation like the primary endpoint is failed and CDN can automatically switch to secondary endpoint, i try use azure traffic manager to do it, based on this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-traffic-manager).

Base on the doc i provide above, based on the step it saids, im quite confused about it, this is my settings:

- Routing method is priority, type of endpoint is external endpoints, test1 with priority 1, test2 with priority 2
- test.trafficmanager.net  ->   which is my traffic manager url, i map it with my Cname test.mydomain.com in azure 365 domain center, Monitor status is degraded in traffic manager profiles
- test1.azureedge.net  ->   which is my primary endpoint, i map it with cdnverify.test.mydomain.com in domain center but i cant map test1.azureedge.net with test.mydomain.com in CDN profile, return 200 when i go to test1.azureedge.net, Monitor status is degraded as well
- test2.azureedge.net  ->   which is my secondary endpoint, i cant set up the map for to cdnverify.test subdomain in domain center, it says "Another DNS record already exists for this host name. Type a different name". Monitor status is degraded as well
- when i go to test.trafficmanager.net, return 404; when i go to both test1.azureedge.net and test2.azureedge.net, return 200

is there any steps wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

you're doing it wrong. CDN is for static content delivery, if there's a problem in one of the cdn nodes, you'll probably won't know, but the content will be delivered automatically by another node. Traffic Manager should be used with VM / Web Apps, then if one of the instances is down, it will failover to another instance / region